# marching band conductor

Tags: number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be the unique polynomial that satisfies:

$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{101}$, for all positive integers $n$.
The leading coefficient of $f(n)$ can be expressed as $\frac {a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive co prime integers. What is the value of $a+b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_k(n)$ is the polynomial defined by $f_k(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$, then the leading coefficient is $\frac{1}{k+1}$ (easy to show by induction).

So we have $a=1$ and $b=102$, and hence $a+b=103$.

Comment: a+b has to be a value between 0 and 999

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam It is between $0$ and $999$ indeed